# Three rectangles with overlapping configuration. Find unknown area

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

This was the question I attempted to answer. I am CalculatorUser and I tried my best to solve it, however, I couldn't and I need help.

**Three 2 x 1 rectangles are arranged as shown. What fraction of the figure is golden?**

[image: Golden Triangles are what you are trying to solve for.]

Go to the link if you want to see my attempt, I really tried hard, but there is no one to help..

https://web2.0calc.com/questions/help_32752

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let the two segment lengths along the long side of the middle rectangle $a$ and $b$. Then,

$$a+b=2,\>\>\>\>\>1+a^2=b^2$$

where the hypotenuse of the golden triangle is $b$, due to the SAA-congruency of golden and grey triangles. Solve to obtain $a=\frac34$ and $b=\frac54$. Thus, the two golden areas sum up to $\frac{3}{4}$, which is $\frac{3}{8}$ of one rectangle.

Comment: The legs of the triangles are $1$ and $a$, not $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro - It is 1 and a, as shown in the diagram as well as in the 2nd equation. Note that b is the hypotenuse.

Comment: Yes, so the area is $\frac{3}{4}$, not $\frac{15}{16}$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro - My bad, Will correct. Thanks